# How does the reduce method work here?

Tags: ruby

I read through the ruby docs examples but I'm still not sure what is happening in this code:

```
sentence = "How are you?"
sentence.chars.reduce do |memo, char|
    %w[a e i o u y].include?(char) ? memo + char * 5 : memo + char
end
```

What is the memo when the block of code is first executed? What do the subsequent 5 steps look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you didn't provide a default value for `reduce`, it will set `memo` to be the first value in `sentence.chars`, which is `"H"`.

Iteration #1:

- `memo` is `"H"`
- `char` is `"o"`
- Result of the block is `"Hooooo"`

The result of the first iteration is then passed into the block as the first argument. So in iteration #2:

- `memo` is `"Hooooo"`
- `char` is `"w"`
- Result of the block is `"Hooooow"`

This will continue for each element of the array and the end result will be the result of the block after it is applied to the last element.

A trivial way to see this in action is just executing the following code:

```
sentence = "How are you?"
sentence.chars.reduce do |memo, char|
  puts "Memo = #{memo}, char = #{char}"
  %w[a e i o u y].include?(char) ? memo + char * 5 : memo + char
end
```

Comment: This is too late I know but I came across this answer and I think 
Iteration#1 

`char will be 'o' not 'e'.`

so the result of the block will be:
    `Hooooo`

and, for block#2, 
   `memo` will be `Hooooo`
   `char` will be `w`
   and the result :  `Hooooow`

Comment: Thanks! I must have used "Hello" or something when I was testing it.